# React Add/Remove list of customize components

Tags: reactjs

I want my items could be add or removed.

Add items is ok, but remove one item will cause rest of items removed either.

I have tried  the plain Object Array could be add/remove by these two functions, but the react element array can not work the same.

[Here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) is I referenced the Delete function.

[Here](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/13638267?key=f5547c66fbdec23afca66f03cfe52e1a) is my problem screen shot.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wescoff-kytwj3?file=/App.js) is code sandbox.

Anyone have suggestions?

Here is code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

export default function List() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  const itemListRef = useRef([]);
  const onDeleteProduct = useCallback(index => {
    console.log("delete " + index);
    setItemList(
        itemList.filter((item, i) => i !== index)
    );
})

function addSelectProduct() {

    let index = itemList.length;
    let newList = [];
    newList.push(
        <Item ref={r => itemListRef.current[index] = r}
            number={index + 1}  onDeleteProduct={() => onDeleteProduct(index)}
        />
    );
    setItemList(prevState => [...prevState,
    ...newList
    ]);
}

function allData() {
  let len = itemListRef.current.lenth;
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(itemListRef.current[i].getData());
  }
}

  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={addSelectProduct}>Add One</button>
    <button onClick={allData}>show All data</button>
      <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th># No.  </th>
                <th>text  </th>
                <th>Operate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {itemList}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </>
  );
}

const Item = React.forwardRef(({ number, onDeleteProduct }, ref) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getData,
  }));
  const getData = () => {
    return data;
}
  return (
      <tr key={number}>
          <td>{number}</td>
          <td><input value={data} onChange={e => setData(e.target.value)}/></td>
          <td>
                <button size="sm" variant="danger" onClick={() => onDeleteProduct(number)}>Delete</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  );
});
```

Comment: React elements are added to `itemList` so comparing with index wont work when deleting, its will be better to map the elements in the markup instead of adding in `itemList`

Comment: You are right, I use a customize id string rather than the list index. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the last version of `itemList`. Maybe you should add `itemList` to the dependencies array of useCallback:

```
const onDeleteProduct = useCallback(index => {
   console.log("delete " + index);
   setItemList(
      itemList.filter((item, i) => i !== index)
   );
}, [itemList])
```

Furthermore, you should use a useCallback in `addSelectProduct` function too with its dependencies.